# How does activerecord-import gem deal with concurrent imports? Does it lock the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the activerecord import gem to import stock price histories whenever someone adds a stock to their portfolio. Before adding stock price history, the function first checks if that stock already exists in the table. That way even when 2 people have the stock Google, it doesn't populate the stock price history twice.

However, this got me thinking to a concurrent add. If 2 people added Google at the same time and the price history wasn't already existing in the model, then the function 'import' would occur twice, at the same time.

Which brings me to my question. Does activerecord-import lock the table to prevent 2 imports at the same time?

Edit: Based on Jim's advice I did the below:

In my Stock model I use an `after_save` to run a function which imports to StockHistory so I lock StockHistory as such:

```
def populatepricehistory

#columns and prices defined here

StockHistory.transaction do
    StockHistory.lock
    StockHistory.import columns,prices
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activerecord-import` doesn't do any explicit locking itself.  If you're doing anything with concurrency, it's best to isolate things explicitly.  Wrap your updates in an [ActiveRecord transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).  You can also be more explicit about locking using ActiveRecord's [pessimistic locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking) mechanism, but that's not necessary most of the time; it's often better to just let one of the transactions fail and to handle the failure.

Wrapping in a transaction is easy:

```
# Inside ActiveRecord model Foo:

def some_bulk_update
  foo_records = generate_some_foo_records()
  transaction do
    self.import foo_records
  end
end
```

It's a good idea to do as much as you can outside the transaction to reduce the window for conflicts.  `generate_some_foo_records()` above is just an example of how you might call a method before the transaction to build the array of `foo_records` to import.

Check out the two links above for details.

Comment: Ty. I updated my question with my function based on what you wrote. It seems pretty straight forward but I wanted a double check since it's hard to replicate a concurrent modification error by myself. Do you see anything wrong with that function? Also the rails guide says .lock implies Lock with Exclusive. Just to confirm that's the same LOCK WITH EXCLUSIVE as postgresql? I ask because the default Lock in Postgresql when using Lock is Lock with Access Exclusive, so I just want to confirm that the rails lock defaults to a different type.

Comment: That looks good to me.  I don't know which locking mechanism it will use, or how to select a locking mechanism, but the easiest way to see what it's going to do is to run the code and look at the SQL it generates in your Rails log.